# Left of the dot precision

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to is to write something like this

```
file << someFunction(5) << hex << 3;
```

And to get an output like this `00003` instead of 3 (and 300 will be 00300, etc)

Note:- Sorry if this was asked before, I don't know what term to search for to get this

EDIT:- I mean the zero's to the left, i included the hex part just to be clear I want it to be compatible with this format

Comment: Do you mean hexadecimal representation, or do you mean padding with zero on the left side? The code seems to point to the former, but the example of input and output seems to point to the latter.

Comment: Is an error or warning spitted out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this is what you mean.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
   std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << 3 << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
00003
```

Links
[`setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw), [`setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill).

Edit: Also, see [`std::internal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17543883/1171191).

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
file << setfill('0') << setw(5) << 3;
```

to get `00003` instead of `3`

Answer (score 2):

iomanip is what you need to search for.

```
#include <iomanip>
```

then

```
file << someFunction(5) << hex << setw(5) << setfill('0') << 3 << endl;
```