# Correctly pad negative integers with zeros with std::cout

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, iomanip

I found this question already asked, but the answer everybody gives is

```
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << value << std::endl;
```

which is fine for positive numbers, but with -5, it prints:

```
000-5
```

Is there a way to make it print -0005 or to force cout to always print at least 5 digits (which would result in -00005) as we can do with printf?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << std::internal << -5 << '\n';
//                                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Output:

```
-0005
```

[std::internal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left)

Edit:

For those those that care about such things, N3337 (`~c++11`), `22.4.2.2.2`:

```
The location of any padding is determined according to Table 91.
                  Table 91 - Fill padding
State                               Location
adjustfield == ios_base::left       pad after
adjustfield == ios_base::right      pad before
adjustfield == internal and a
sign occurs in the representation   pad after the sign
adjustfield == internal and
representation after stage 1 began
with 0x or 0X                       pad after x or X
otherwise                           pad before
```

Comment: You're very welcome! This question went nice and quickly. Hope this helps other people too.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20 you'll be able to use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```cpp
std::cout << std::format("{:05}\n", -5);
```

Output:

```
-0005
```

In the meantime you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that makes this even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sW6KTb)):

```
fmt::print("{:05}\n", -5);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.